# boost fusion- what exactly is the emphasis of the compile-time abilities?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, template-meta-programming, boost-fusion

I have a few questions regarding boost::fusion

1) What exactly is the emphasis on the compile-time capabilities of fusion? Is it just to "glue" template metaprogramming with "normal" run-time programming (hence they say fusion is the mixing of compile time with run time code)? If so, I thought you could combine metaprogramming with normal run-time C++ already?

2) Does fusion only work with tuples? I seem to see tuples in all the fusion examples. Or, is tuple just an example of a fusion "sequence" and tuple, along with other types can count towards a fusion sequence?

3) Again, trying to understand fusion- how does fusion differ from a framework to allow generic coding? We have templates for that right? Again, is the emphasis on fusion being with the compile-time programming?

4) Are there any prerequisite boost libraries one needs to know in order to use fusion? I have seen/heard MPL mentioned a few times.

**5) What are the areas in which fusion most used?**

6) Why do a lot of the metaprogramming (compile-time) functions return types?

Any additional advice regarding boost fusion is most appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the Boost.Fusion documentation full of examples which cover at least 50% of your questions?

Comment: @KerrekSB to be completely blunt there was 2 or 3 paragraphs which don't answer my questions and then the remaining 200-odd pages just list the API (which isnt very helpful) and the examples were 2 or 3 liners.

Comment: For example, how can you map values to types, without Boost.Fusion?

Comment: Maybe best to break it down into separate questions... I know that Fusion is huge, but this question seems to be asking a lot.

Comment: (Also, question 5 is loaded: Who claimed that Fusion was "very useful"? Wouldn't it be OK if it was just sort-of useful?)

Comment: @KerrekSB have modified it. Would you be able to answer #6? That may help me to understand the rest.

Comment: @user997112 metafunctions *always* return types, by definition.